# How can I display high frequency data in Angular 2 without tiggering 'value has changed after it was checked' error?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular2-pipe

I'm trying to display a count down timer, but I'm having a hard time. I basically store a `startTime`, and then use a pipe to calculate and display the difference.

Here's my pipe

```
@Pipe({
    name: "timeDiff",
    pure: false
})
export class TimeDifferencePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(start: Date, end?: Date): string {
        if (start === null) return "";

        end = Util.isDate(end) ? end : new Date();
        let diff = new Date(end.getTime() - start.getTime());

        let min = diff.getMinutes();
        let sec = diff.getSeconds();
        let mil = diff.getMilliseconds();

        return `${min}:${("00" + sec).substr(-2, 2)}:${("0000" + mil).substr(-4, 4)}`; 
    }
}
```

The code works, but I get the error of `Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '0:00:0004'. Current value: '0:00:0008'.`

I'm aware of [idempotence expressions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#idempotence), but how then do you display data that has a high frequency of change?

Comment: Using setInterval() to change the model in your component.

Comment: @JBNizet There's no better way?